# hash merge vs assignment

Tags: ruby, hash, idioms

I have a simple case of a hash that's passed along that is missing a field.

I'm wondering which is the preferred way of adding the field with some default and whether or not are there benefits to choosing one over the other and when?

```
hash['field'] = some_value
```

vs

```
hash.merge!({ 'field' => some_value })
```

edit: meant to use merge!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, an important note: `Hash#merge` returns a *new* object, whereas `Hash#[]=` and `Hash#merge!` mutate the *existing* object:

```
hash = {a: :b}

hash.merge(c: :d) # => {a: :b, c: :d}
puts hash # => {a: :b} (!!!)

hash[:c] = :d
puts hash # => {a: :b, c: :d}

hash.merge!(e: :f)
puts hash # => {a: :b, c: :d, e: :f}
```

The main use-case for using `Hash#merge!` over `Hash#[]=` is (as the name suggests!) when you have two existing hashes that need to be merged together:

```
hash1 = {a: :b, c: :d}
hash2 = {e: :f, g: :h}

hash1.merge!(hash2)
puts hash1 # => {a: :b, c: :d, e: :f, g: :h}
```

This is equivalent to, but more convenient than, the much more verbose approach of looping through all values in `hash2`:

```
hash2.each do |key, value|
  hash1[key] = value
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering which is the preferred way of adding the field with some default

I'd store the defaults in an extra hash (even if it is just a single value), so I can easily add other values later:

```
defaults = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

Then, I'd merge the defaults in a way that preserve the given value, either by creating a new hash:

```
hash = { foo: 100, baz: 300 }
hash = defaults.merge(hash)
#=> {:foo=>100, :bar=>2, :baz=>300}
```

or by changing the hash in-place:

```
hash = { foo: 100, baz: 300 }
hash.merge!(defaults) { |key, given_value, default_value| given_value }
#=> {:foo=>100, :baz=>300, :bar=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first approach changes the hash itself (no new object is created)

the second creates new instance of Hash class with keys from both original `hash` and `{ 'field' => some_value }` (compare `object_id` of `hash` and of result of `hash.merge({ 'field' => some_value })` - they'll be different)

which one to choose?
it depends - if changing state of `hash` is not a problem for you, then the first approach is ok.